# PHP serialize() is not properly serializing stdClass object

Tags: php, google-app-engine, serialization

I have an application running on Google App Engine (using PHP 5.5.38), and I'm using a Laravel package for caching query results.

This worked well for a similar project, but for this one, I get errors such as, "unserialize(): Error at offset 14 of 860 bytes" (the numbers vary, depending on what was serialized.)

The error occurs in a class that has only these two functions:

```
public function encode($data){
    return serialize($data);
}

public function decode($data){
    return unserialize($data);
}
```

I found that when testing the app locally, everything works correctly, and the serialized data looks something like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":27:{s:2:"id";i:2;s:10:"first_name";s:4:"Zach";...
```

But when I run it on App Engine with the same data, it returns this:

```
a:1:{i:0;O:8:"@*lass":27:{s:2:"id";i:2;s:10:"first_name";s:4:"Zach";...
```

It might not show here, but there are invisible characters next to the '*' (in notepad++, they show up as [ENQ] and [DLE]).

I believe that the call to unserialize() fails because the serialized data contains @*lass instead of stdClass, but I don't know what's causing it, or how to prevent it. I tried using str_replace, and it worked at first, but not for everything. I also made sure that PHP was using UTF-8 as the default charset.

*EDIT:* I modified the encode function to try to pinpoint the moment the trouble starts.
I now have:

```
public function encode($data)
{
    $serialized = serialize($data);
    try{
        unserialize($serialized);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($serialized);
        die;
    }
    return $serialized;
}
```

And when it's executed on the server, it outputs:

```
a:1:{i:0;O:8:"@*lass":27:{s:2:"id";i:2;s:10:"first_name";s:4:"Zach"; ...
```

So it seems like the problem starts with before anything is saved or unserialized.

Comment: how do you save and load the string?

Comment: Have a look at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67363

Comment: The string is saved to a redis cache, but I believe that the problem starts before that. See my edit above.

Comment: I don't know what else to try.
When I try using the flex environment in App Engine, it defaults to php7.1, but then it fails when running composer because one or more of the packages we're using requires 7.0 or less.

Comment: It sounds like this could be an instance of [this previously reported issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/35899850) for PHP in App Engine standard. Does that sound correct to you? As for App Engine Flexible, it is possible to [choose your PHP version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#choosing_a_php_version).

Comment: It's possible that that issue is related. It's a strange issue though, I've never had any other problems with stdClass. I'm working on getting it to work with the flex environment now (that a whole other mess though). If needed, I can even use Compute Engine instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not an ideal fix, but this seems to work...

```
public function encode($data)
{
    return serialize(json_decode(json_encode($data), true));
}

public function decode($data)
{
    return json_decode(json_encode(unserialize($data)));
}
```

The problem seemed to come from serializing an array of stdClass objects, so I figured it would help to convert stdClass to associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
$data_serialized = serialize($data);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).